# Missing slf4j in tess4j

Tags: java, ocr, tess4j

I want to test tess4j to do OCR. I used the following tutorial for a first example: http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/codesample.html
I included the required libraries, but I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at tess4jexample.TesseractExample.main(TesseractExample.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

Does anyone knows a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has where still some dependencies missing, which have not been mentioned on the mavenrepository:

- logback-core-1.1.6.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar

I think now it is working :-) Thank you nguyenq for this hint, to check the dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Tess4J has several [dependencies](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.tess4j/tess4j/3.1.0). You'll need to include them in the classpath.

Comment: Yes, I got all these dependencies included. I still get the same error.